# cherrypick not giving all the files

Tags: git, github, gerrit

Has anyone run into a problem where you cherrypick a gerrit and all the files are not present?following is the sequence of commands I do..
any thoughts on what could be the reason?
are there ways other than cherrypicking to sync a file?

```
repo init -u git://git.company.com/platform/manifest.git -b jb_2.2_rb2_5
repo sync vendor/com/proprietary/code
git fetch ssh://username@review-android.company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/code refs/changes/42/185542/2 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was changes in the files being cherry-picked are already present